# Sql exception while creating database in android

Tags: android, arrays, database, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I am creating `SQLite` Database in App. I need to Store `String` value in Table.This are the `Table` name and coloumn name required to create database.

```
// Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "note";

    // Table Names
    private static final String TABLE_TABLES = "tableslist";

    // TABLES Table - column nmaes
    private static final String ALL_TABLES = "Table";
```

This is my statement to create database as

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_TABLELIST=" CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_TABLES+ "(" + ALL_TABLES + " TEXT "+ ")";
```

This is method in to add record in Table in Class which extends `SqLiteOpenHelper`

```
 public void addAllTables(String tab){
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
        values.put("table",tab);
        db.insert(TABLE_TABLES,null,values);
    }
```

In Fragment I am inserting value as

```
DatabaseHelper db=new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
   db.addAllTables(response.toString());
```

where response is my `JSONArray` which I need to store in Database as a String.I am getting exception as
`android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Table": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE tableslist(Table TEXT )`
How to resolve this ?

Comment: `Table` is a reserved word, you can't use it as a name of the column

Comment: private static final String CREATE_TABLE_TABLELIST=" CREATE TABLE 
 " + TABLE_TABLES + "( " + ALL_TABLES + "  " + "TEXT "+ ");";   Spaces between +, are not important, just make code looks better, but rest of it is